# How to publish raster data in Arcgis Viewer for Flex?

Tags: raster, arcgis-server, arcgis-flex-api, arcgis-flex-viewer

I'm new to ArcGIS for Server and I would like to publish several raster layers (land surface temperature, NDVI etc.). I have uploaded raster to server, but I cannot add it to my ArcGIS viewer for flex. Is it possible?
If not, what is the best solution to publish raster layer that is located in ArcGIS server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to publish separate map services for each of your rasters layers. One for your DEM. One for NDVI. You should cache them for better performance. Then in your config file for flex, add your RESt endpoints to these services as operational layers.